# Как сделать чтоб стили применялись к вновь созданным элементам?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Задаю стили для select через jQuery (не бейте).
Есть необходимость при клике на кнопку добавлять новый ряд input'ов и select'ов.
Как сделать чтоб к добавленному ряду тоже применялись стили.
Сразу скажу, я новичок, код js не мой, нашел на просторах и адаптировал под себя

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select').each(function() {
        const _this = $(this),
            selectOption = _this.find('option'),
            selectOptionLength = selectOption.length,
            selectedOption = selectOption.filter(':selected'),
            duration = 450; // длительность анимации 
    
        _this.hide();
        _this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');
        $('<div>', {
            class: 'new-select',
            text: _this.children('option:disabled').text()
        }).insertAfter(_this);
    
        const selectHead = _this.next('.new-select');
        $('<div>', {
            class: 'new-select__list'
        }).insertAfter(selectHead);
    
        const selectList = selectHead.next('.new-select__list');
        for (let i = 1; i < selectOptionLength; i++) {
            $('<div>', {
                class: 'new-select__item',
                html: $('<span>', {
                    text: selectOption.eq(i).text()
                })
            })
            .attr('data-value', selectOption.eq(i).val())
            .appendTo(selectList);
        }
    
        const selectItem = selectList.find('.new-select__item');
        selectList.slideUp(0);
        selectHead.on('click', function() {
            if ( !$(this).hasClass('on') ) {
                $(this).addClass('on');
                selectList.slideDown(duration);
    
                selectItem.on('click', function() {
                    let chooseItem = $(this).data('value');
    
                    $('select').val(chooseItem).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    selectHead.text( $(this).find('span').text() );
    
                    selectList.slideUp(duration);
                    selectHead.removeClass('on');
                });
    
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('on');
                selectList.slideUp(duration);
            }
        });
    
        
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.add').click(function(v){
            v.preventDefault(),
            $('#person').append('<div class="form__row"><div class="topic"><input type="text" required><div class="form__placeholder">Имя</div></div><div class="topic"><input type="text" required><div class="form__placeholder">Фамилия</div></div><div class="topic topic-3"><select class="select" name="language"><option disabled></option><option value="36">36 р.</option><option value="37">37 р.</option><option value="38">38 р.</option><option value="39">39 р.</option><option value="40">40 р.</option><option value="41">41 р.</option><option value="42">42 р.</option><option value="43">43 р.</option><option value="44">44 р.</option><option value="45">45 р.</option></select><div class="form__placeholder">Размер обуви</div></div></div>')
        })
    });
```

```css
.form__row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.topic {
  margin: 0 3px;
  border: 2px solid #D2D2D2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.topic .form__placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.topic input {
  border: none;
}
.select {
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 7px 23px 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  max-width: 152px;
  width: 100%;
}
.select .new-select {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  min-height: 15px;
  width: 82px;
}
.select .new-select:after {
  content: url(;../img/form/arrow-down.svg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.select .new-select__list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 22px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.select .new-select__list.on {
  display: flex;
}
.select .new-select__item span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.select .new-select__item span:before {
  content: url(../img/service-marker.svg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 7px;
}
.select .new-select__item span:hover {
  color: #465177;
  background: #eee;
}
.select .new-select:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 4px;
  background: url("../img/form/arrow-down.png") no-repeat right top;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.27s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.select .new-select.on:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  class="form-2" method="POST">
  <fieldset id="person">
    <div class="form__row">
      <div class="topic">
      <input type="text" required>
      <div class="form__placeholder">
        Имя
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="text" required>
      <div class="form__placeholder">
        Фамилия
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="topic">                         
      <select class="select" name="language">
          <option disabled></option>
          <option value="36">36 р.</option>
          <option value="37">37 р.</option>
          <option value="38">38 р.</option>
          <option value="39">39 р.</option>
          <option value="40">40 р.</option>
          <option value="41">41 р.</option>
          <option value="42">42 р.</option>
          <option value="43">43 р.</option>
          <option value="44">44 р.</option>
          <option value="45">45 р.</option>
      </select>                         
      <div class="form__placeholder">
        Размер обуви
      </div>
    </div>                                          
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  <a href="#education-fields" class="add">Добавить еще</a>       
</form>
```

Comment: Если стили прописаны в css, они будут применяться для динамически создаваемых эл-тов

Comment: @InDevX должны, но на деле все не так

Comment: На деле всё так. Ваша проблема решается очень легко...

Comment: @InDevX просветите пожалуйста

Comment: Не верно формулируете вопрос - главная проблема. Никаких стилей через jq не добавляете, вы только заново формируете эл-т

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё достаточно просто: Вы стилизируете select (по-факту, вы его создаёте) только при загрузке страницы, по-этому, когда вы добавляете новый эл-т - вид остаётся прежний. Единственное что нужно - при добавлении нового эл-та делать то же самое что делаете при загрузке страницы. Для этого просто обернул код в функцию дабы избежать дублирования, и добавил для блоков класс new, посредством добавления/удаления которого "показываю" какой эл-т нужно стилизировать.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  updateSelect();
  $('.add').click(function(v){
    v.preventDefault(),
    $('#person').append('<div class="form__row new"><div class="topic"><input type="text" required><div class="form__placeholder">Имя</div></div><div class="topic"><input type="text" required><div class="form__placeholder">Фамилия</div></div><div class="topic topic-3"><select class="select" name="language"><option disabled></option><option value="36">36 р.</option><option value="37">37 р.</option><option value="38">38 р.</option><option value="39">39 р.</option><option value="40">40 р.</option><option value="41">41 р.</option><option value="42">42 р.</option><option value="43">43 р.</option><option value="44">44 р.</option><option value="45">45 р.</option></select><div class="form__placeholder">Размер обуви</div></div></div>');
    updateSelect();
  });
});

function updateSelect(){
    $('.form__row.new').find('.select').each(function() {
    const _this = $(this),
          selectOption = _this.find('option'),
          selectOptionLength = selectOption.length,
          selectedOption = selectOption.filter(':selected'),
          duration = 450; // длительность анимации 

    _this.hide();
    _this.wrap('<div class="select new"></div>');
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'new-select',
      text: _this.children('option:disabled').text()
    }).insertAfter(_this);

    const selectHead = _this.next('.new-select');
    $('<div>', {
      class: 'new-select__list'
    }).insertAfter(selectHead);

    const selectList = selectHead.next('.new-select__list');
    for (let i = 1; i < selectOptionLength; i++) {
      $('<div>', {
        class: 'new-select__item',
        html: $('<span>', {
          text: selectOption.eq(i).text()
        })
      })
        .attr('data-value', selectOption.eq(i).val())
        .appendTo(selectList);
    }

    const selectItem = selectList.find('.new-select__item');
    selectList.slideUp(0);
    selectHead.on('click', function() {
      if ( !$(this).hasClass('on') ) {
        $(this).addClass('on');
        selectList.slideDown(duration);

        selectItem.on('click', function() {
          let chooseItem = $(this).data('value');

          $('select').val(chooseItem).attr('selected', 'selected');
          selectHead.text( $(this).find('span').text() );

          selectList.slideUp(duration);
          selectHead.removeClass('on');
        });

      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        selectList.slideUp(duration);
      }
    });
    
    this.closest('.form__row').classList.remove('new');
  });
}
```

```css
.form__row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.topic {
  margin: 0 3px;
  border: 2px solid #D2D2D2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.topic .form__placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.topic input {
  border: none;
}
.select {
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 7px 23px 5px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  max-width: 152px;
  width: 100%;
}
.select .new-select {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  min-height: 15px;
  width: 82px;
}
.select .new-select:after {
  content: url(;../img/form/arrow-down.svg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.select .new-select__list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 22px 35px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.select .new-select__list.on {
  display: flex;
}
.select .new-select__item span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.select .new-select__item span:before {
  content: url(../img/service-marker.svg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 7px;
}
.select .new-select__item span:hover {
  color: #465177;
  background: #eee;
}
.select .new-select:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 14px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 4px;
  background: url("../img/form/arrow-down.png") no-repeat right top;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: all 0.27s ease-in-out;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.select .new-select.on:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  class="form-2" method="POST">
  <fieldset id="person">
    <div class="form__row new">
      <div class="topic">
      <input type="text" required>
      <div class="form__placeholder">
        Имя
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="topic">
      <input type="text" required>
      <div class="form__placeholder">
        Фамилия
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="topic">                         
      <select class="select" name="language">
          <option disabled></option>
          <option value="36">36 р.</option>
          <option value="37">37 р.</option>
          <option value="38">38 р.</option>
          <option value="39">39 р.</option>
          <option value="40">40 р.</option>
          <option value="41">41 р.</option>
          <option value="42">42 р.</option>
          <option value="43">43 р.</option>
          <option value="44">44 р.</option>
          <option value="45">45 р.</option>
      </select>                         
      <div class="form__placeholder">
        Размер обуви
      </div>
    </div>                                          
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  <a href="#education-fields" class="add">Добавить еще</a>       
</form>
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо